# When groupbox is on another groupbox function cannot find groupbox

Tags: c#, search, groupbox

The program I am making requires a lot of user input.  A command is selected by the user and the corresponding groupbox is made visible and I save the current groupbox for later use.  The code below works flawlessly IF the groupboxes are not overlapping in the GUI. What I want is to be able to stack all of the groupboxes on top of each other and this to still work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < funcCodes.Length; i++)
  {
    byte z = funcCodes[i];
    GroupBox gb = (GroupBox)Controls["gbDisplay_FC" + z];
    if (z == zcontrol.getFunctionCode())
    {
        gb.Visible = true;
        currentGB = gb;
    }
    else
        gb.Visible = false;
  }
```

The failure I get is when they are stacked gb becomes null (cant find the groupbox)  Thanks for any help pretty new to C#.

Edit1:
The below comment works as well as if you just change the location of the groupbox using the properties vs drag and drop that makes it a child.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for your control name then using Controls.Find() like this:

```
        Control[] gbs = this.Controls.Find("gbDisplay_FC" + z.ToString(), true);
        if (gbs.Length > 0 && gbs[0] is GroupBox)
        {
            GroupBox gb = (GroupBox)gbs[0];
            // .. do something with "gb" ...
        }
```

This will work whether the GroupBoxes are contained directly by the Form, or are "stacked" causing them to be contained by one another.

Comment: Still having a few issues but you just got me a lot closer.  Didn't realize it was making them contained in another one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah...that's a common "bug".  It's not obvious what happens at first.  Usually we see this question asked with Panels instead of GroupBoxes

Comment: +1 have experienced the same problem a long time ago bud didn't think about it right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Then simply add a null check

```
for (int i = 0; i < funcCodes.Length; i++)
  {
    byte z = funcCodes[i];
    GroupBox gb = (GroupBox)Controls["gbDisplay_FC" + z];


    if(gb == null)
      continue;


    if (z == zcontrol.getFunctionCode())
    {
        gb.Visible = true;
        currentGB = gb;
    }
    else
        gb.Visible = false;
  }
```

Comment: I understand what you mean here but that does not solve the issue as it needs to find the groupbox that is on top of the other groupbox in the GUI. Checking for null is good programming practice and I should have that in the code already.

Comment: But as you said it's null if it couldn't be found. And it can't be found if it doesn't exist. So how do you want to find it if it doesn't exist? :)

Comment: Oh sorry I must have not made myself clear. All of the groupboxes are on the form.  I should never get null and I dont when the groupboxes are right next to eachother on the form but when I put the groupboxes on top of eachother I do.

Comment: how do you add them to the form?

Comment: A picture is a better explanation. What I have that works. (See how they are next to each other) https://www.dropbox.com/s/kello7ndwpc80eh/whatIHave.PNG  Where I want them to be so when one is visible and the others are not they are in the same location. (You cant see the other groupbox as they are on top of each other. I dragged it on top.) https://www.dropbox.com/s/897v4d4h89l79ji/whatINeed.PNG